# Vuforia recognizes targets, but the target display location seems to be different

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm in need of help

```
Vuforia recognizes targets, but the target display location seems to be different

used engine = unity
platform = hololens2 (uwp)
used vuforia version = 10.14.4
```

#### The following presupposes based on normal operation in the UnityEditor.

#### The purpose is to operate accurately in the HoloLens2.

I checked the log, but when the Vuforia recognizes the target, it is generated in a position coordinate that is significantly different from the one checked by UnityEditor

I think.. it's probably related to Vuforia DevicePoseBehaviour, so I used All public mathod but It didn't help to break through this situation.
RecenterPose(),Reset(),SetStaticMode(bool)

I don't know if it helps, but OnBecameVisible() didn't work either in hololens2.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any transform offsets on your target object for example?

Comment: it's just normal cube, I tried several times under controlled conditions, Also image target generated by usual mathod. (by right click on hierachy) Plus,as I explained above, it works fine in the editor. Only in HoloLens 2

Comment: When I checked in the editor, the camera direction changed significantly when VuforiaEngine recognized the target, but in game view clearly showed the image target object. It's a little suspicious, but it's the same phenomenon as the Hololens2 sample provided by Vuforia, so it doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Have you checked the setup in the provided Vuforia sample projects?

Comment: I don't think it's a setup issue because put it on top of it based on the sample project.